# How i will set banner or how i will remove this space from my page

Tags: php, html, css

[image][image: my panel banner]

hi..i have made this panel but tagged red color is space...i cannot remove this space from this page .

or it will be suitable for if i can set a banner.

below code is for reference...

```
 </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
    <div><h2 style="background-color:#00CCCC" align="center" "height:50px" width="550px" >SMS Panel</h2></div>
      <div class="col-sm-2">
          <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked" style="background-color:#FFCCFF">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Subscriber info and message</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#">Home</a>
              </li>
            <li><a href="#">Show subscriber</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">unknown menu</a></li>
          </ul>
```

Comment: Can you provide a demonstration? Am sure this is because you must be using `margin-top`

Comment: @Mr.Alien...thank u...but i am not using margin-top...i have used here bootstrap.framework...class...container..then it is auto coming...

Comment: Can't comment unless you show me a working example, till then I can just blindly guess whats going on behind the scenes

Comment: @sazal can you upload your css? we have a more possibilities to solve your question

Comment: "height:50px" in the h2 is invalid as an attribute. It should be in the style attribute (or set in a style element or sheet...). 'align' is considered obsolete in the h2, and you should use text-align in css.

Comment: Does your document have a doctype?

Comment: For your reference ...please see the link...it is not properly working for as like showing in my laptop...what i will do http://jsfiddle.net/Sazal/g2khLdtb/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is difficult to tell what is the exact problem without looking at the complete code. I will take a stab on it. It might be happening because you are not doing CSS reset for the panel. Many HTML elements have non zero margin by default. You can read more about CSS reset [here](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/).

To fix this issue you can give appropriate negative margin-top to the element right below the panel. It will have problems in IE7 and older browsers but will work in all modern browsers. To find the actual root cause of the issue you need to inspect the panel element in Chrome inspector or Firebug and need to check if there is any margin or padding either for the panel or the element right below it.

Update:
As per the given fiddle you need to add the following rule

```
h2, ul {
    margin: 0; 
}
```

[Updated fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/g2khLdtb/6/)

Comment: You need to add these two CSS rules h2 {margin: 0; } and .col-sm-2 {margin-top: -16px; } after that it will work.

Comment: @Diptendu....its working for me...thank u...but if i see from mobile it is not showing as like laptop browser showing....

Comment: Which browser you are using in mobile ? Is it iOS or Android ?

Comment: Android...if it is suitable for you i will share screenshot..browser is Mozilla firefox

Comment: Yes, that will be helpful. I wanted to check what exactly is not working in mobile. Is it Chrome or android native browser ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67749/discussion-between-sazal-ahmed-and-diptendu).

Answer (score 2):

Your h2 tag has a margin on the bottom of about 5 or 10px, if you set the margin on the bottom to 0 it will remove the space.

Answer (score 0):

You didnt use a `<div class ="row">` tot wrap up your layout. Certain styles are only applied when you use the row `div`

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

Replace this line of code

```html
<div class="col-sm-2">
```

to

```html
<div class="col-sm-2" style="margin: -20px 0px 0px ! important;">
```

i.e according to your code : http://jsfiddle.net/g2khLdtb/1/ you have posted on above comment